# Alternate solutions For Parsing Huge file

Tags: java, file

I am having two files input1.csv and input2.csv whose sizes are huge.

input1.csv has three columns A,B and C(B is unique in this file).

input2.csv has 2 columns B and C.

I want to check how many times each occurance of B has occurred in input2.csv file.

I have implemented by storing value B from the input1.csv file in the arraylist and used hashmap with key as B's value and value as B's occurance in the input2.csv file. 
This logic works fine but execution time increases when file size increases.Also have finished the code in the main method itself. Is there any other logic to solve this problem??? Since I am new to java can any one provide me a good design pattern for this solving this problem?

Program:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String comma = ",";
        Map<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<String>  arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input1.csv"), encoding));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            String val = line.split(comma)[1];
            arrayList.add(val); //Value to be later used
            hashMap.put(val,0);
        }
            reader.close();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input2.csv"), encoding));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            String val = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","));
            if(hashMap.get(val) !=null) {
                hashMap.put(val, hashMap.get(val) + 1);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        printMap(hashMap);    
    }
    public static void printMap(Map mp) {
        Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From your description it seems to be a fine solution. If you're just checking/increasing values in the hash map you should not be experience major decelartion,  hash maps are O(1) amortized. You should post your code, I believe you have some coding issues which are not related to the core algorithm.

Comment: Hi @lexicore have updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is more or less fine. I don't think you can do it much more optimal.

A few comments:

- You actually never use `arrayList`. If you really need to check that values from the second file are present in the first file you should create a has set instead and check for `contains` - but only when encountering a new value.
- You access the map several times (`hashMap.get(val)`, then `hashMap.put(val, hashMap.get(val) + 1)`). Simply saving `hashMap.get(val)` in a variable would remove one of the accesses.
- Use mutable `AtomicInteger` as value. You could avoid `hashMap.put` by just `incrementAndGet` on the value.
- With `AtomicInteger` you could just `hashMap.putIfAbsent(value, new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet()`.